# Is it a memory leak to push_back a pointer into a vector of pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, vector, c++11

In my class, I have a member variable `std::vector<node*> children`

Does the following class member function create a memory leak?

```
//adds a child node
{
    node* child = new node("blah","blah","blah");
    child->Set_Parent(this);
    children.push_back(child);  //<- Is this ok?
}
```

The vector makes a copy of the pointer and I have two pointers to the same memory,
and then the original pointer goes out of scope, right?

This may be simple and obvious,  but I would just like to confirm my assumption.
thanks

Comment: I suggest you look into smart pointers, like [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: You can even use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) in this case, as `std::vector` supports move semantics.

Comment: If nodes are always supposed to have parents you can make it a part of the constructor. Then you only need `children.push_back(new node("blah","blah","blah"), this);`

Comment: @ddriver oh, sneaky! and I'll just pass in nullptr when I build the root

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not a leak ... yet. However, if the `vector` goes out of scope, or you `erase`, `pop_back` or do something else that removes elements from the vector, without first `delete`ing the element that you're removing you'll have a leak on your hands.

The right way to do this is to change from using a `vector<node *>` to `vector<unique_ptr<node>>`. Your code will change to

```
//adds a child node
{
    node* child = new node("blah","blah","blah");
    child->Set_Parent(this);
    children.push_back(std::unique_ptr<node>(child));
}
```

Or use `boost::ptr_vector<node>` if you can use Boost.

Comment: Yeah, I could avoid raw pointers, but them I wouldn't get the practice of tracking down memory leaks! :)
Didn't know boost had a class like that! thanks

Comment: The last line can simply be `children.emplace_back(child);`

Answer (score 2):

It's only a memory leak if you forget to deallocate the children node when the class containing the vector's destructor is called.

Comment: great! thank you.  Yeah, my destructor loops through the vector, and deletes each pointer.  I find no reason to set them to null since the pointers will shortly disappear as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a memory leak. You still have a pointer in the vector and you will be able to free the memory when needed.

Answer (score 1):

When the vector goes out of scope, it's destructor doesn't destroy the pointed-to object. It destroys the pointer -- which does nothing.

Your code created that object via `new`. Your code is responsible for deleting that object. If you don't do so, you have a leak. If you do so to early, i.e., before removing the pointer from the vector, you have even bigger problems.

Answer (score -3):

Assuming `children` is a class member you would just simply delete all the items in the vector on the class deconstructor.

```
struct Foo{};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(){};
    ~Bar()
    {
        for( vector<Foo*>::iterator it = children.begin(); it != children.end(); ++it )
        {
            SAFE_DELETE( (*it) ); //use your own macro/template or use delete if you don't have one
            delete (*it);
            (*it) = NULL;
        }
    }
    vector<Foo*>children;
}

Foo* p = new Foo();
children.push_back( p );
```

If you used a `vector<Foo>child` instead, every `push_back` on the vector would create a copy of the original object to be stored, but since you're using pointers, in this case allocated on the heap by `new` no object copy is created, the pointer that points to a long-life term object is simply stored, meaning yes, you have to delete it later.

Comment: That makes sense.  I don't think I need to set them to null though since the whole object will be destroyed.  I don't understand the purpose of the macro/template.

Comment: I didn't get it right, You don't think you need to set a pointer to NULL when deleting it?. `safe_delete` has been a known macro/template for ages, it's purpose is to safely delete a heap allocated item. I recommend you reading effective/more effective c++ from from David Mayhew and Scott Meyers.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this is silly. `SAFE_DELETE` isn't safe; all it does is check whether the pointer is null before invoking `delete`. There is nothing wrong with deleting a null pointer. There is no need for that test; there's no need for using `SAFE_DELETE` instead of just using `delete`. To make `SAFE_DELETE` truly safe it would somehow have to check whether a non-null pointer truly was allocated with `new` prior to invoking `delete`. It doesn't do that. There's also no reason to set the pointer to `NULL` after deleting it; we're in the destructor.

Comment: I could write at least 2 examples where `safe_delete` outuses a simple `delete` call. Setting a pointer to 0 (which is "null" in standard C++, the NULL define from C is somewhat different) avoids crashes on double deletes. There are many possibilities, the pointer could be shared, have references. If you say "Hey there is nothing wrong not setting pointers to null after I delete them, I've seen plenty of other programmers do it and their program works fine"

Comment: is the same than "Aw, this gun's safety is a pain to set
all the time. And anyway, some other people don't use it either, and some of them haven't shot their own feet off…".

At least in my enviroment, with multithreaded server/client applications, running the same part of a code thousands of time per second. Safety practices are the minimal

Comment: The problem is that `SAFE_DELETE` is neither safe nor necessary. Now I am one of the downvoters.

Comment: If that is your `opinion`, ok

Comment: If you need to set pointers to null in the destructor of the objects that own them in order to avoid double deletes you have bigger problems. Basically, your objects don't have a well-defined lifetime or ownership, and instead of curing that, you're hiding the symptoms. (And did someone mention that this class violates the rule of three?)

Comment: This is an small example to answer the related question, if you want to apply your skeptical narcissism talking about rule of three on a `vector`, `memory leak` question small piece of code example I am sure you're quite a WG21 erudite. I agree with your point about the objects lifetime definition, but not all code reduces to this example. Heap isn't friendly, I'd rather set pointers to null instead of dealing with obscure memory debugging later.

Comment: How could anyone, ever, quote the rule of three when dealing with a memory leak? That thing that deals with memory leaks.. against a memory leak? VAT IZ ZIS

Comment: Whenever you say `delete` in your code, you're doing it wrong.